# How to install npm 3 beta on Windows?

Tags: npm

I've tried running `npm install npm@3 -g` but my npm is still at 2.x:

[image: NPM still at v2.x]

How to install the latest beta?

Answer (score 2):

It was a PATH issue - `c:\Program Files\nodejs` had higher priority than `%APPDATA%\npm` which was causing npm to be stuck at the older version.